# Why is there a gap on the right side of child image imported from within the main input file?

Tags: standalone

### Child input file

```
% Child.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\pagecolor{yellow}

\setlength\PreviewBorder{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,3)
\psframe[linecolor=red](4,3)
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

### Main input file

```
% Main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\fboxsep=0pt

\begin{document}
\fbox{\input{Child}}
\end{document}
```

`Main.tex`, which is compiled with `xelatex.exe`, produces the following result. Why is there a white gap on the right side of the imported image?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a space because of the line break after the `\end{document}` in the child document. You need to place the usual `%` there to avoid it. Alternatively using `\input{Child}\unskip}` should also do it.

Comment: So should I do it for all cases such as when the child input file just contains equations rather than PSTricks code?

Comment: It might be a good idea to add `\endinput` after `\end{document}` in documents used with **standalone**.

Comment: @egreg: The `\end{document}` (in sub-files) already contains `\endinput` (of course! :-) ). I now added `\@ignoretrue` as well which removes the space. It's funny that the line break is still taken as space even with the `\endinput` in place.

Comment: I don't want to create a new question just for asking this: "Is there an option to use in a child input file such that I no longer need to specify `\setlength\PreviewBorder{0pt}` explicitly in each child input file?"

Comment: @xport: There is the `border` class option for the `standalone` class, e.g. `border=0pt`. Note that if you `\input` child documents then the source code is read and `preview` is not used.

Comment: Will you fix this bug in the next version or leave it as is as a feature? :-)

Comment: @xport: What? The original issue? Like I already wrote above I fixed it already in the develop version.